# Washing Machine won't Spin due to weak stands, how to reinforce?

Tags: washing-machine

We have a Whirlpool touch screen washing machine that doesn't initiate the spin cycle. We have had multiple service calls to make sure it isn't a blocked drain line, sensor, power issue, etc. We have followed all the load recommendations, tried everything and anything for load size and weight.

The last tech that came out pointed out the whirlpool stands we purchased are particularly shakey and poorly made and that could be causing it. I like the stands and drawers because I cannot reach the cabinets above the washer. So before we completely remove them, I was wondering how to reinforce them? My guy is very handy and can easily build something if that's what it takes. We also have a new construction/home with the flexible basin underneath if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can see if the spin cycle started shaking the machine....the machine would shut itself down.  But if the spin cycle isn't even starting...it's not the stands.   You didn't inadvertently turn on the "No Spin" option did you?   (I use that option to wash golf balls).

Comment: I have to agree with Steve Wellens on this.  There is no way the machine knows, "The stands are shaky." so I'm not going to spin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to stay mum on *if* this is your problem, and concentrate on the question you asked.

We have our washer up on a stand. We wanted to put laundry baskets under it, so the entire thing is constructed of a lag bolted 4x4 frame with 4x4 legs and 3/4" plywood for the top, with marmoleum flooring on top of the plywood. It's absurdly solid and will happily let the washer vibrate the whole house with an unbalanced load. Assuming your laundry floor is solid, a well built wood frame should be quite strong, either 2x with cross bracing or made of 4x.